# is it possible to computation user time-on site when open a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any way to computation user time-on site when open an external website link from iframe or any other option in a new tab?

I want to develop an advertising system, but it is important to report our customers, the users time-on site which are came from my advertise system, but we don't want to use google analytic or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, what you have to do is calculate how long the user stay on your page, and send it back on your server when the user leave the page/iframe:

```
var startTime = new Date();
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    var endTime = new Date();
    var timeSpent=(endTime - startTime);
    // HERE YOU MAKE YOUR AJAX REQUEST INCLUDING timeSpent
}
```

Comment: I don't have any access to that external websites, I just open them from my website in a new tab (from iframe or div).

Comment: Insert this code in your page, and do an iframe of the external website.

Comment: But I want to open sites in new tab, not in an iframe.